# Check if RadioButton is NOT selected

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I have this logic in my code

`if(r40.isChecked()){
     //do this
 }`

It works great, but I needed the negative, "if rb.isNotChecked" or ".isChecked() = false"

But I cant see to find it, also I can't use the RadioGroup because all my RadioButtons are not inside one, I'm controlling them manually

Comment: When comparing a two values, you use two (2) equal signs. ".ischecked() = false" doesn't work because it's not a comparison. the correct comparison is ".ischecked() == false".

Comment: you should literally read ANY book about ANY programming language EVER. This is just a disgrace, what you've asked.

Comment: also, preceding your check with a "!" means "if this is not true" so you can do "!rb.ischecked" link in the answers posted. "!" means not

Comment: @Vucko It's in my todo list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean you COULD do 
`if(r40.isChecked() == false){
//do something
}` 
BUT 
`if(!r40.isChecked){
//do something
}` 
 Is much better/cleaner

Answer (score 2):

> But I cant see to find it

```
if(!r40.isChecked()){
  //do this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with negative check

```
if(!r40.isChecked()){
     //do this
 }
```

this check if radio **isn`t** checked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (! r40.isChecked()) {    

       //Do something 
}
```

**In more detail the exclamation mark added in this code reverses the following code in the same block, causing the code to mean:**

```
if (r40.isNotChecked()) {

       //Do something
}
```

***I hope this helped!***